# python - vlookup in pandas applying %LIKE%

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python, and I am trying to join two CSV files (delimited by ";")

```
CSV1
Sender;Recipient
Adam;123
Alex;234
John;123
Adam;888

CSV2
Name;Phone
Winnie;123,234,456
Celeste;777,888,999
```

Intended Output:

```
Sender;Recipient;RecipientName
Adam;123;Winnie
Alex;234;Winnie
John;123;Winnie
Adam;888;Celeste
```

`Phone` in `CSV2` is separated by comma(s). So I need to do some kind of search or `%LIKE%` when I am matching.

I know I can use `join` to do a vlookup type but how can I achieve the `%LIKE%`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `str.split` to turn `Phone` column into lists
- Use `str.len()` to find the length of each of those lists.  We'll use this to explode the `'Name'` column
- Push all those lists together into one.  Make sure to filter out zero length lists
- Use `repeat` to explode `'Name'`
- Create a dictionary where keys are phone numbers and values are names
- Create a copy of `d1` where we've added the new column using `map` and the new dictionary we made.

---

```
p = d2.Phone.str.split(',')
p = p[p.astype(bool)]
l = p.str.len()
p2 = np.concatenate(p.values).astype(int)
nm = d2.Name.repeat(l)
m = dict(zip(p2, nm))

df = d1.assign(RecipientName=d1.Recipient.map(m))
print(df)

  Sender  Recipient RecipientName
0   Adam        123        Winnie
1   Alex        234        Winnie
2   John        123        Winnie
3   Adam        888       Celeste

df.to_csv('out.csv', sep=';', header=None)

Sender;Recipient;RecipientName
Adam;123;Winnie
Alex;234;Winnie
John;123;Winnie
Adam;888;Celeste
```

Comment: hello, thanks very much for this. do you mind explaining the code a little so that i can learn from it too? I also got stuck at trying the `concatenate`. It says "zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated"

Comment: @chongzixin see if that helps.

Comment: How do you import the csv's? What if I wanted to apply this to my own data set?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
from  itertools import chain

#split values by `,` to lists
lens = df2['Phone'].str.split(',')
#if some zero list remove it
df2 = df2.dropna(subset=['Phone'])

#explode Names by length of lists, flat values by chain.from_iterable
s = pd.Series(np.repeat(df2.Name.values, lens), 
              index= list(chain.from_iterable(df2.Phone.values)))
#convert index to int for match
s.index = s.index.astype(int)
print (s)
123     Winnie
234     Winnie
456     Winnie
777    Celeste
888    Celeste
999    Celeste
dtype: object
```

---

```
#map values to new column
df1['RecipientName'] = df1['Recipient'].map(s)
print(df1)
  Sender  Recipient RecipientName
0   Adam        123        Winnie
1   Alex        234        Winnie
2   John        123        Winnie
3   Adam        888       Celeste

#write to csv
df.to_csv('out.csv', sep=';', header=None)

Sender;Recipient;RecipientName
Adam;123;Winnie
Alex;234;Winnie
John;123;Winnie
Adam;888;Celeste
```

Solution with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) is similar:

```
df2['Phone'] = df2['Phone'].str.split(',')
df2 = df2.dropna(subset=['Phone'])

s = pd.Series(np.repeat(df2.Name.values, df2.Phone.str.len()), 
              index= list(chain.from_iterable(df2.Phone.values)))
s.index = s.index.astype(int)
s.name = 'RecipientName'
print (s)

df1 = df1.join(s, on='Recipient')
print(df1)
  Sender  Recipient RecipientName
0   Adam        123        Winnie
1   Alex        234        Winnie
2   John        123        Winnie
3   Adam        888       Celeste
```

EDIT:

My data samples:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""
Sender;Recipient
Adam;123
Alex;234
John;123
Adam;888"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";")
print (df1)
  Sender  Recipient
0   Adam        123
1   Alex        234
2   John        123
3   Adam        888

temp=u"""
Name;Phone
Winnie;123,234,456
Celeste;777,888,999"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";")
print (df2)
      Name        Phone
0   Winnie  123,234,456
1  Celeste  777,888,999
```

Comment: I am failing at the `np.repeat(df2.Name.values, lens)`, it's telling me that `Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'`. `lens` is of dtype:object but I dont know how to convert it.

Comment: Hmmm , if use `lens = lens[lens.astype(bool)]` it works?

Comment: Nope :( And when I tried to `print lens` it was still of `dtype:object`. Is it supposed to be converted into an array?

Comment: Do you use `df1 = pd.read_csv('CSV1', sep=';')` and `df2 = pd.read_csv('CSV2', sep=';')` ?

Comment: and if yes, and still problem, what is `df1.info()` ?

Comment: Yup I used `delimiter=';'` instead of `sep=';'` but I guess it shouldnt make a difference. `df1.info` just prints out everything in df1. But I didnt touch `df1` at all so that shouldnt make a difference?

Comment: Please check my data samples, for me it works perfectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142711/discussion-between-chongzixin-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode and an idea on how to do this.

I would start by parsing the CSV2 file. Skip the first line, then for the following lines parse out the name & phone, then maintain a dictionary of which name is associated with each phone number.

```
numbers_to_names = {}
for line in open("csv2", "r").splitlines():
    name, phone_numbers = line.split(";")
    for phone_number in phone_numbers.split(","):
        numbers_to_names[phone_number] = name
```

Then when going through CSV1 again skip the first line, then parse out sender and recipient and combine with dictionary results from before.

```
for line in open("csv1", "r").splitlines():
    sender, recipient = line.split(";")
    print "%s;%s;%s" % (sender, recipient, numbers_to_names[recipient])
```